# Join query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1267

I have two tables: members and renewals

The two tables have a field called memberid which links the two data tables together.  I am trying to construct a query which will extract the firstname and surname from the members table for the data that is being held in the renewals table.  I have tried using the query below which is based on some examples I've looked up.

```
SELECT members.memberfirst, members.membersurname, members.memberid, renewals.account_name, renewals.memberid 
FROM members, renewals 
WHERE renewals.memberid=members.memberid
```

The error I get when trying to run this in phpMyAdmin:

```
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

[image]

Comment: Can we have a look at your table definitions, please?

Comment: I've edited the original post with screenshot attachment from phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `INNER JOIN`. Take a look here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html
Even if it's for PostgreSQL, the queries are the same for MySQL and the examples are really good.

```
SELECT members.memberfirst, members.membersurname, members.memberid, renewals.account_name
FROM members
INNER JOIN renewals
ON members.memberid = renewals.memberid
```

or you can use `USING (memberid)` instead of `ON members.memberid = renewals.memberid`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I'm still getting the same error message when I run it: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=' I've updated the original post with a screenshot from phpmyadmin of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification if you wanted to display the member's name in a single column

```
SELECT CONCAT(members.memberfirst, " ", members.membersurname) as memberName, 
members.memberid, renewals.account_name, renewals.memberid 
FROM members
INNER JOIN renewals
WHERE renewals.memberid=members.memberid
```